# getting error in multi selected spinner in android

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am using multi selection spinner to update languages to the server but i am getting error in it here is the image attached.[image: in this image i am getting error with <code>onItemSelected</code>]

it is not allowing me to add the method (`onItemSelected`) here. and i have to store and array of selected item's slug and send that to the server using retrofit.

Comment: Don't post code as image

Comment: is it harm full? @barbsan

Comment: ok @barbsan next time i will be careful

Answer (score 0):

There is an example [here](https://github.com/apptik/multiselectspinner/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/apptik/widget/multiselectspinner/example/MainActivity.java) of how to use this spinner

`setListAdapter()` only take on parameter, you have to call setListener to set the listener.

```
english.setListAdapter(adapter)
       .setListener(new MultiSelectSpinner.MultiSpinnerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemsSelected(boolean[] selected) {
                    ... //your code
                }
            })
       .setSelectAll(true)
       .setMinSelecteditem(0);
```

Comment: Thanks i got it.... can you please tell me how to perform actions on the selected items in onItemsSelected.

Comment: how to get the key against each selected value

Comment: well, the `boolean[] selected` is the list you want to work with. If your multi select list contains 3 value like, french, english and spanish and you select french and spanish, the selected array will be [true, false, true], I don't know what you want to do with that so i can't help you much more than that. you can ask another question descrbing exactly what you want

Comment: according to your example i have select french and Spanish now i want to get the slug/key against each selected value and   save the slug/key in an array and send that array to server using retrofit.

Comment: I don't really know about retrofit but [here](https://pastebin.com/415KmDx5) is a code snippet to help you

Comment: it puts every item that is checked in an arraylist of string and call the `send()` method that you will have to do that will send the data via retrofit. I looked back at the code and you can replace `toSend.add(arrayList_english[j]);` by `toSend.add(arrayList_english.get(j).getValue());` I did not see the arrayList_english was a list of custom items but the working is the same